# How can I suppress warnings due to external library installed by setup.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gcc, setup.py

I've coauthored a Python package (let's call it "M") that has a number of dependent Python packages. The dependent packages are listed using `install_requires` in M's `setup.py` file. When users run `python setup.py install` for our package M, the process of installing one of those dependencies (let's call it "L") involves the compilation of an external C++ library if the user does not already have L installed. The compilation may generate a number of gcc warnings. I know the reasons for the warnings, and the issues are benign. I would like to **suppress** the printing of those warnings when a user runs `setup.py install` for our package M.  At first, I thought that putting the following in `setup.py` for M would work,

```
setup (
  ...
  extra_compile_args = ['-Wno-enum-conversion', '-Wno-strict-prototypes'],
  ...
)
```

but it turns out to do nothing – the warnings are still printed when the Python installation tools install the dependency L.

How can I suppress the warnings when users run `python setup.py install` for M?

Comment: Are you sure your warnings are coming from the compilation part (and are you sure you've cleaned your build/temp folders from the previous build without the applied `extra_compile_args` warning suppression)? `extra_compile_args` should most definitely be passed to `gcc` and the specified warnings should be suppressed. However, if the warnings are coming from linking, use `extra_link_args` instead. For a full option list check the [`distutils.core.Extension`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.Extension) documentation.

Comment: Yes, I am certain the warnings are coming from compilation, because I can see the warnings and I know the package it's coming from (I'm actually a coauthor of that one too). Note that the package being compiled is a dependency: in other words, M's `setup.py` says that another package L must be installed, and _it is L that involves compiling an external library_, not M. My understanding is that defining `Extension` in M's `setup.py` will have no effect on L's installation. Am I wrong?

Comment: That's right, your `extra_compile_args` and `extra_link_args` will be applied only on the extension you're building directly from your `setup.py` so they will not have effect on the packages the `L` is building. There might be a way to affect the (current) global `CFLAGS` to achieve that, tho, given that distutils inherits `CFLAGS`...

Comment: I'll be damned. You're right! I tried setting `os.environ['CFLAGS']` in M's `setup.py`, and it worked. Thank you for that idea.

Comment: Glad it worked. A word of caution, tho - changing the `CFLAGS` will affect everything else running under your `setup.py` so if a package `L` depended on a package `J`, the same flags would be applied when compiling `J` as well.